# EXTJS 7.00 Htmleditor problem with enablecolor:true

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs, htmleditorkit

I have this problem using the htmleditor on extjs , everytime i put the enablecolors option i have this error
this is the code:

```
Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init(), 
        new Ext.panel.Panel({
            title: 'Encabezado',
            width: 550,
            height: 200,
            frame: true,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: {
                xtype: 'htmleditor',
                enableColors: false,
                enableAlignments: true,
            },
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        })
```

The code like this works like charm , but when change the value of enable colors to "true" i get the next error , many squares with different colors , is there another way to add htmleditor , what are the possible causes of this problem, thanks

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10cfwD-NqqDyqBeFveYfLSmdjcpXHoLug/view?usp=sharing

I want the option to work like this

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4bv&view/editor

but everytme y enablecolors:true I got the same error

Comment: Hello there, I have created a fiddle of your code, it works: [link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3oom) is there something i missed?

Comment: Maybe some lost css declaration is conflicting with the colorbox, check if you made changes to the following css : .x-component x-color-picker x-box-item x-component-default x-menu-item-cmp